# Material UI form inputs get messed up when I plug the form component into another page? (Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I created a component for my contact form, and am trying to import it into a  on my contact page. When I do this, the styling of the inputs gets totally thrown off... they show up as tiny boxes on the right of the screen. What am I missing here?

Messed up form inputs:
[image]

This is a Next.js app. I've also noticed that on the initial load of the page, this issue doesn't occur... it's only when I refresh.

Here's my form component:

```
import { 
Button, 
FormControl, 
InputLabel,
OutlinedInput} from '@material-ui/core'; 

import styles from '../styles/ContactForm.module.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

const ContactForm = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`
        Name: ${name}
        Phone: ${phone}
        Email: ${email}
        Message: ${message}
    `);
};

return (
    <form id={styles.contactForm} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <FormControl 
            fullWidth 
            className={styles.formInput}
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary">

            <InputLabel htmlFor="name">Name</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput
                color="primary"
                id="name"
                labelWidth={50}
                value={name}
                onChange={(event) => {setName(event.target.value)}}
                required/>   
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl 
            fullWidth 
            className={styles.formInput}
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary">

            <InputLabel htmlFor="phone">Phone</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput
                color="primary"
                id="phone"
                labelWidth={50}
                value={phone}
                onChange={(event) => {setPhone(event.target.value)}}
                required/>   
        </FormControl>
        
        <FormControl 
            fullWidth 
            className={styles.formInput}
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary">

            <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput
                color="primary"
                id="email"
                labelWidth={50}
                value={email}
                onChange={(event) => {setEmail(event.target.value)}}
                required/>   
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl 
            fullWidth 
            className={styles.formInput}
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary">

            <InputLabel htmlFor="message">Message</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput
                color="primary"
                id="message"
                labelWidth={50}
                multiline rows={8}
                value={message}
                onChange={(event) => {setMessage(event.target.value)}}
                required/>   
        </FormControl>

        <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit">Submit</Button>

    </form>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

Here is my contact page component (where the inputs get messed up). The only CSS I have is making `.formWrapper` have a width of 500px:

```
import ContactForm from '../components/ContactForm';
import styles from '../styles/contact.module.css';

const contact = () => {
    return (
        <main id={styles.contact}>

            <section className={styles.formWrapper}>
                <ContactForm />
            </section>

        </main>
    );
};

export default contact;
```

Any ideas on why my inputs are doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue here was the fact that NextJS renders on the server, so the MUI classes were not matching up correctly when I re-rendered the page. I was able to fix the problem by following this documentation:

https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/